# Normalize CRLF line endings in Django form input

Tags: python, django

I have a ModelForm with a TextArea. If the user submits text with a newline, it gets converted into a \r\n by the browser. I would expect Django to normalize this text for me, but it doesn't.

This is an issue because Django's `maxlength` validation doesn't line up with the `maxlength` in HTML, since in-browser lines endings are treated only as "\n".

So if the textarea has a maxlength of 5, and the user enters `"ab\ncd"`, they think that's fine, but when they submit the form, Django error because it sees `"ab\r\ncd"`, which is 6 characters. I want to fix this by doing everything with `\n`, and not save `\r\n` into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by overwriting the to_python method on the form Field. This runs as part of serializing the form data into python, so it happens before any field validation or cleaning (which could otherwise error due to incorrect line lengths). Note that this is different from overwriting the widget (which controls how the form displays in HTML) or the model field (which controls how the data is stored in the database).

```py
from django.utils.text import normalize_newlines

class MyCharField(forms.CharField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        # NOTE: No security guarantees are made about this code
        return super().to_python(normalize_newlines(value))
```

And then overwriting the field used in the form like so:

```py
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            "text": forms.Textarea() # Unchanged
        }

        field_classes = {
            "text": MyCharField,
        }
```